# iOS UISlider Customization. Showing highlight from the center

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uislider

I am trying to create a slider for my app similar to the one shown below. I tried doing it in interface builder but no luck. The default slider always shows highlight from the left. How can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: We you able to figure out the solution. I am planning to implement the same, it would be great if you can help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UISlider` doesn't have built-in support for what you want to do.  It's probably best to write your own subclass of `UIControl` or `UIView` instead of trying to customize a `UISlider`.

But if you really want to customize a `UISlider`, here's what you need to know.

A `UISlider` has three private `UIImageView` subviews: one for the thumb, one for the track to the left of the thumb, and one for the track to the right of the thumb.  When you drag the thumb or change the slider value programmatically, the slider sends itself `layoutSubviews`.  In its `layoutSubviews` method, it changes the frames of the three image views to match the new slider value.

You shouldn't mess with `UISlider`'s private subviews.  They might change in a future release of iOS.  Instead, you want to effectively disable the track image subviews so you can draw your own track, and leave the thumb image subview alone so `UISlider` will take care of showing the thumb.

You'll need to subclass `UISlider`.  In your subclass, you'll need to do several things:

- You'll need to set your `minimumValueImage` and `maximumValueImage` properties to a transparent `UIImage`. This will effectively disable the private `UISlider` subviews that draw the normal two-part track.
- You'll need to give yourself three new `UIImage` properties: `leftEndImage`, `rightEndImage`, and `filledImage`.  You'll use these to fill the three different parts of your track.
- You'll need to give yourself three `UIImageView` subviews - one for each of the three parts of the track.
- You'll need to override `layoutSubviews`.  In your method, you need to call `[super layoutSubviews]`, then set the frames of your three image subviews to match the current value of the slider.

It could be a little complicated if you're new to iOS programming.  Good luck.

### UPDATE

Actually, it occurs to me that you could set `minimumValueImage` to a left-right mirror of the default `maximumValueImage` image, so that `UISlider` will draw both of the white ends of your three-part track.  Then you just have to add one `UIImageView` subview of your own to draw the blue part of the track.

However you do it, if you subclass `UISlider` and insert subviews, you are depending on `UISlider`'s implementation not changing too much.  If, for example, a future version of `UISlider` draws the track and thumb directly in `drawRect:` instead of using subviews, your subclass will certainly look wrong.

Comment: Thank you rob for explaining (+1). I'll wait for a while before marking as answer. Any ideas if there are any already implemented projects with similar control? (open source?)

Comment: I have never looked for any such projects and don't know if any exist.